# Return type format of this website

Tags: ajax, json, return-type

I just came across this site
[erail](http://erail.in/rail/getTrains.aspx?Station_From=CSTM&Station_To=DAZ&DataSource=0&Language=0&Cache=true) I want to know the type of returned data format,its neither json nor xml,Whats it,please help me.
Thank u

Comment: maybe it's just an array which is user defined. do you need to use this results?

Comment: The transmitted data is encrypted

Comment: may be the down voters should comment or answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a custom format. The ~ look likes field delimters with some fields with an inner structure where a , .  or :  is used as a delimeter, the ^ is the record delimiter. The first field is a number and the first record is different from the next ones which seem to be identical in field structure.

If you want to use that in javascript you have to write your own deserializer...